# how much free space is left for mysql on lampp

Tags: mysql, lampp

I have a server on which I have installed lampp. I can access my databases and their tables via phpmyadmin on my browser and size of them is visible on size column but I can't see the free space of mysql database. How can I understand how much free space is left for mysql on lampp and How can I expand it?

Comment: There's as much free space for mySQL as there is free space on the disk (or, if you have per-quotas, for the user mySQL runs as).

Comment: @Pekka웃 do you mean /opt/lampp/mysql directory?

Comment: I don't know where your copy of mySQL stores its data but that might well be it.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of free space available for your database is dependent on the file system where the data directory resides. Since you're using LAMPP, it will depend on where the LAMPP package installs things. I think it's `/opt/lampp/` but I'm not sure; most distribution's package managers seem to use `/var/lib/`. You can find out the datadir path on your system by looking at the output of the MySQL `STATUS;` command.

If you've partitioned your drive, then of course you'll be limited by the specific partition on which that is mounted, otherwise you should have the whole disk available.